# Convert Gigabytes to Bytes

Tags: php

I am in the position where I am trying to convert gigabytes to bytes from a submit form. I have searched around and I am unable to find anything suitable.
Currently when converting bytes to gigabytes I use this method, which works perfectly.

```
public function byteFormat($bytes, $unit = "", $decimals = 2) 
{
    $units = array('B' => 0, 'KB' => 1, 'MB' => 2, 'GB' => 3, 'TB' => 4,
    'PB' => 5, 'EB' => 6, 'ZB' => 7, 'YB' => 8);

    $value = 0;
    if ($bytes > 0) {
    // Generate automatic prefix by bytes
    // If wrong prefix given
    if (!array_key_exists($unit, $units)) {
    $pow = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
    $unit = array_search($pow, $units);
    }

    // Calculate byte value by prefix
    $value = ($bytes/pow(1024,floor($units[$unit])));
    }

    // If decimals is not numeric or decimals is less than 0
    // then set default value
    if (!is_numeric($decimals) || $decimals < 0) {
    $decimals = 2;
    }

    // Format output
    return sprintf('%.' . $decimals . 'f '.$unit, $value);
}
```

There seems to be plenty of examples of bytes to other formats but not the other way around.

I have seen that I can convert the number 1.5 like so

```
round(($number[0] * 1073741824));
```

The result is `12992276070`, however, when using the byteformat method shown above, I get the following `1610612736`, this seems quite a difference between the two methods.
Can anyone suggest a more stable method for converting gigabytes to bytes.

Comment: "The result is 12992276070" --- why do you think so?

Comment: Yes... in your test, you seem to be using 12.1, not 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two different unit symbol, decimal and binary.
As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Unit_symbol), decimal multiplication is by 1000 and binary by 1024.
so if you are using "B"(byte), just do something like:

```
$bytenumber=$giga*pow(1024,3);
```

if using "b"(bit) :

```
$bitnumber=$giga*pow(1000,3);
```

P.S:$giga is your giga number.

Comment: Yes, and i think OP was asking suggestion for a stable method. I am sorry if i was wrong. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get as accurate of a conversion as there are numbers after the decimal place. If you start with 1.29634 gigs you'll get a closer representation to it's actual byte value versus calling it 1.3 Gigs. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

```
numberOfBytes = round (numberOfGb * 1073741824)
```

is the exact answer to your question. It seems, you have miscalculated. Try to check it on a calculator.

The other problem is that if you have the source number of 2 digits, it is incorrect to give an answer in more or less than 2 digits. The correct counting will be:

```
source: 1.5GB
counting: 1.5GB*1073741824 B/GB= 1610612736 B
rounding to the last significant digit: 1610612736 B ~= 1.6e9 B
answer: 1.6e9 B
```

But, of course, many clients do not really want the correct answer, they want THEIR answer. It is up to you to choose.